# iPad Docks: Alesis iO Dock or Tascam iU2 

Tags: ipad

I have just been given some funding to buy an iPad and audio/MIDI interface to do some research (synthesis-based sound design).  Having done a bit of research on interfaces against my requirements I've now narrowed it down to either the [Alesis iO Dock](http://www.alesis.com/iodock) or [Tascam iU2](http://www.thomann.de/gb/tascam_iu2.htm?gclid=CNDbk-6u6rUCFcrHtAodAX4AQg)

I'm leaning towards the Alesis on the grounds of standard connectors and looks better build quality.  As anyone used either?  I'm particularly interested to hear about build quality, robustness and quality of the pre-amps.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

We use the Alesis i/o docks at our studio. They are made of plastic, so I doubt they're made to travel, but they work really well & I haven't had any problems with connectivity. I'll admit I've only used the preamps a couple of times for sampling or auditions but had no complaints. we mostly use them as midi interfaces & pro quality outputs to Pro Tools. There's some incredible apps for synthesis & sound design on the iPad & having a dock immediately transforms your tablet into a professional sound module. well worth the $$$.

Comment: @Rawly thanks for your answer.  I don't think I will really be traveling with it, but I'm hoping to use it a sketch-pad for ideas. Just wanted to check it is not likely to fall apart as soon as looking at it.  (In the pics the Tascam looks a bit flimsy.) Like you I have studio so probably won't use the audio inputs too much, but I do have quite a few vintage synths so I will use the MIDI connectivity.  Just did not want to find out after buying that the audio inputs are unusable. 

Answer (score 0):

I thought it would be worth posting an update incase anyone else is planning a similar purchase.

Following my research and the received advice, I put in an order request an iPad3 and the Alesis iO Dock (unfortunately I don't actually do the purchasing myself).  The dock arrived earlier this week and yesterday an iPad4 was delivered. Unfortunately, on the latest iPad the traditional 30-pin connection has been replaced by a Lighting connector and the iO Dock is not compatible as it has the 30-pin connection....Doh!!!!

From the [Alesis support site](http://community.alesis.com/alesis/topics/ipad4_and_existing_alesis_io_dock) it appears that the Apple 30-pin to Lightning converter may offer a solution......I shall keep you posted.